# Python: 'int' object is not iterable in map.Pool

Tags: python

For some reason,

```
result = pool.map(_delete_load_log,list(logs_to_delete))
```

is now giving me an 'int' object is not iterable error.

as per the screenshot, logs_to_delete is clearly an array (added list() to see if it changed anything, and nope). This worked earlier, but I can't track back what changed to make it not work. Any ideas?

[image]

mapping function:

```
def _delete_load_log(load_log_id):
    logging.debug('** STARTING API CALL FOR: ' + get_function_name())
    input_args = "/15/" + str(load_log_id)
    logging.debug('url: ' + podium_url + '\nusername: ' + podium_username)

    podium = podiumapi.Podium('https://xx/podium','podium','podium')
    #podium = podiumapi.Podium(podium_url,podium_username,podium_password)
    data = None
    response_code = 0
    try:
        api_url = PodiumApiUrl(podium_url,input_args)

        (response_code,data) = podium._podium_curl_setopt_put(api_url)
        if not data[0]['hasErrors']:
            return data[0]['id']
        elif data[0]['hasErrors']:
            raise Exception("Errors detected on delete")
        else:
            raise Exception('Unmanaged exception while retrieving entity load status.')
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception(str(err))
```

---

```
File "c:\Repos\Tools\podium-dataload\scripts\podiumlogdelete.py", line 69, in _delete_source_load_logs_gte_epoch
    deleted_load_ids = _delete_logs_in_parallel(load_logs_to_delete)
  File "c:\Repos\Tools\podium-dataload\scripts\podiumlogdelete.py", line 85, in _delete_logs_in_parallel
    result = pool.map(_delete_load_log,logs_to_delete)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 253, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: 'int' object is not iterable
```

output of list:

[154840, 154841, 154842, 154843, 154844, 154845, 154846, 154847, 154848, 154849, 154850, 154851, 154852, 154853, 154854, 154855, 154856, 154857, 154858, 154859, 154860, 154861, 154862, 154863, 154864, 154865, 154866, 154867, 154868, 154869, 154870, 154871, 154872, 154873, 154874, 154875, 154876, 154877, 154878, 154879, 154880, 154881, 154882, 154883, 154884, 154885, 154886, 154887, 154888, 154889, 154890, 154891, 154892, 154893, 154894, 154895, 154896, 154897, 154898, 154899, 154900, 154901, 154902, 154903, 154904, 154905, 154906, 154907, 154908, 154909, 154910, 154911, 154912, 154913, 154914, 154915, 154916, 154917, 154918, 154919, 154920, 154921, 154922, 154923, 154924, 154925, 154926, 154927, 154928, 154929, 154930, 154931, 154932, 154933, 154934, 154935, 154936, 154937, 154938, 154939]

Comment: Looks impossible. Provide the trace back please.

Comment: @liliscent added traceback

Comment: Use `print(logs_to_delete)` `print(type(logs_to_delete))`. That will at least give you some indication of what's happening; you'll need to do some debugging first

Comment: a gist also may be useful and more readable.

Comment: @roganjosh added. looks like a normal list :|

Comment: That's why you'll also want to check the type

Comment: Image  code doesn't match the code posted

Comment: @cricket_007 i removed some extra debug lines for readability as per request above

Comment: replace `map(_delete_load_log,list(logs_to_delete))` to `map(_delete_load_log,[logs_to_delete])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is clear from the traceback. It's not caused by the iterable in `Pool.map()`, otherwise the exception would be raised from Python source code line

```
iterable = list(iterable)
```

Here the exception is raised from

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 253, in map
return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 572, in get
raise self._value
```

This is because your `_delete_load_log()` raised some exception, and Pool.map re-raise it. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py

In other words, `Exception: 'int' object is not iterable` is *not* from the python library part, it's from your own function `_delete_load_log()`.

Comment: that was it. never had a bug within a mapper before. thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, just take a close look at

```
#podium = podiumapi.Podium(podium_url,podium_username,podium_password)
data = None
response_code = 0
try:
```

The response code is equivalent to 0, although the traceback function isn't inputted as "invalid", it makes you have to re-patch a lot afterwards.